# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Epi'

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am writing a stored procedure but when i tried to execute it this error pops up:

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Epi'.
```

I've been going through the codes a lot of times but still can't figure out where the problem lies. I need a fresh pair of eyes, please!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rpt_Provider_GP_Monthly_Dump]
    @DateOption VARCHAR (100) = 'Service Date', -- 'Service Date' or 'Approval Date'
    @FromDate   DATETIME,
    @ToDate     DATETIME,
    @Provider   VARCHAR (100) = 'ALL'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @FromDate   = CONVERT(DATETIME, @FromDate , 103)
    SET @ToDate     = CONVERT(DATETIME, @ToDate , 103)

    /* Variable Declaration */
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(2000)

    SET @SQLQuery = '
    SELECT CLM.ClaimCode, CLM.ClaimNumber, CLM.VisitAdmissionDate,
    CASE
        WHEN (MBR.SubsidiaryCode IS NULL OR MBR.SubsidiaryCode = '''') THEN MBR.ClientCode
        ELSE MBR.SubsidiaryCode
    END AS CompanyCode,
    CASE
        WHEN (MBR.SubsidiaryName IS NULL OR MBR.SubsidiaryName = '''') THEN MBR.CompanyName
        ELSE MBR.SubsidiaryName
    END AS CompanyName,
    PROV.ProviderCode, PROV.ProviderName, MBR.MemberCode, MBR.MemberName,
    CLM.OnInvoiceGrandTotal, SUM(CLM.PayByInsGrandTotal + CLM.PayExgratiaGrandTotal) AS PaidAmt, CLM.ApprovedDate,
    CASE
        WHEN CLM.IsOvrdCoInsCoPayAmt IS NULL THEN ISNULL(CLM.CoInsCoPayAmt,0)
        ELSE ISNULL(CLM.OvrdCoInsCoPayAmt,0)
    END AS CopayCoIns,
    SUM(CLM.CoverageByClientGrandTotal + CLM.CoverageByMemberGrandTotal + CLM.ExceedLimitGrandTotal + 
    CLM.DuductibleAmtGrandTotal + CLM.MemberCoInsGrandTotal + CLM.CoverageByProviderGrandTotal) AS RejectedAmt,
    CLM.DiagnosisCode, CLM.DiagnosisDescription,
    STUFF( (SELECT '', '' + A.Description FROM CLM_ClaimBenefit A
            WHERE A.BenefitType = ''DRG'' AND A.ClaimCode = CLM.ClaimCode ORDER BY A.Description
            FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE)
    .value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, '''') AS Drug,
    ISNULL(STUFF( (SELECT '', '' + CAST(A.Qty AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM CLM_DrugFormulary A
            WHERE A.ClaimCode = CLM.ClaimCode ORDER BY A.DrugName
            FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE)
    .value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, ''''), '''') AS Qty,
    STUFF( (SELECT '', '' + CAST((A.PayByIns + A.PayExgratia) AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM CLM_ClaimBenefit A 
            WHERE A.BenefitType = ''DRG'' AND A.ClaimCode = CLM.ClaimCode ORDER BY A.Description
            FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE)
    .value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, '''') AS Amount,
    CLM.ClaimStatus, ISNULL(CLM.ClaimHandlerRemarks, '''') AS ClaimHandlerRemarks, CLM.CreatedBy
    FROM CLM_Claim CLM, CLM_MemberDetail MBR, CLM_ProviderDetail PROV
    WHERE MBR.ClaimCode = CLM.ClaimCode AND PROV.ClaimCode = CLM.ClaimCode
    AND CLM.ClaimClassCode = ''BC000001''
    AND CLM.ClaimStatusCode IN (2, 9, 13)
    AND CLM.ClaimTypeCode = 1
    AND CLM.EpisodeNumber = (SELECT MAX(EpisodeNumber) FROM CLM_Claim WHERE ClmNo = CLM.ClmNo)
    '

    IF (@DateOption = 'Approve')
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND CLM.ApprovedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate + 1'
    ELSE    -- Visit Date
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND CLM.VisitAdmissionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate + 1'

    IF (@Provider != 'ALL')
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND PROV.ProviderCode = @Provider'

    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' 
    GROUP BY CLM.ClaimCode, CLM.ClaimNumber, CLM.VisitAdmissionDate, CLM.ApprovedDate,
    MBR.ClientCode, MBR.CompanyName, MBR.SubsidiaryCode, MBR.SubsidiaryName, 
    PROV.ProviderCode, PROV.ProviderName, MBR.MemberCode, MBR.MemberName, 
    CLM.OnInvoiceGrandTotal, CLM.IsOvrdCoInsCoPayAmt, CLM.OvrdCoInsCoPayAmt, CLM.CoInsCoPayAmt,
    CLM.DiagnosisCode, CLM.DiagnosisDescription, CLM.ClaimStatus, CLM.ClaimHandlerRemarks, CLM.CreatedBy
    '

PRINT @SQLQuery
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery, 
        N'@DateOption VARCHAR (100), @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME, @Provider VARCHAR (100)',
        @DateOption, @FromDate, @ToDate, @Provider
END
```

Comment: I can't see it. Doubling up the quotes looks ok - I can't where "EPI" exists on it's own (outside of the word "Episode") though, is this passed as parameter value? Are you sure this is the bit of code causing the problem?

Comment: When I did a PRINT @SQLQuery it halts at this part "AND CLM.EpisodeNumber". Removing all the STUFF works fine though. I am trying to work around this using a WHILE loop instead.

Comment: You've declared `SQLQuery` as NVARCHAR(2000) - could the query string be exceeding that length? Try increasing it to 4000 or ideally, NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Right on spot @Bridge. Right on spot! Thank you ever so very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(2000)
```

to

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```